# cakephp: sessoin issue with facebook login

Tags: php, session, cakephp, facebook-login

I have implemented FB login in my app. For noraml login session is working fine. But when login with Fb and try to write data and redirect back to home page session is showing null.

```
// fb login successfull
if(!empty( $result )){
   $this->Session->write('user', $result['User']);
   //debug($this->Session->read('user'));
   $this->redirect("/home");
   }else{
// error
}
```

At home controller

```
function index(){
debug($this->Session->read('user'));
}
```

it is showing null. But when i put session_start() at top then session data is available. What's wrong with cakephp session.

Comment: http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-facebook-login-using-cakephp-facebook-login-plugin

Comment: https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth